# MAUI android rendering page

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin.android, .net-maui

I am starting using the visual studio 2022 v. 17.3 preview 2
In the startup program that shows the dotnet_bot image and a button with text " Click Me"

now when you click the button text will change to "Clicked 15 times" ( number change accoring to count value according the following code:

```
private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        count++;

        if (count == 1)
            CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
        else
            CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";
        
        SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);
    }
```

so the text will change but the button size will not adjust .. and the text will be clipped  as the following image:

[image]

I tried to search online and on github and microsoft documentation..
I couldn't find out how to force the button to adjust its size to the text property

This happen only in Android but not in windows

I tested android phone emulator (Pixel 5 API 30 (Android 11.0 )
Same behavior on android tablet (Tablet M-DPI 10.1in - API 31 ( android 12)

The solution I found which is not accepted is

to use any entry element that will make the keyboard pop out.. then and only then the page will re-render and the button will expand to show the full text "clicked 15 times"

So my question is :

What am I missing here?
How to force the page to rerender?
Or is it a bug in MAUI ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Yes,it is a known issue in android.

You can follow it up here:

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/8136

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8028

But as a workaround,you can try to change the property of Button `CounterBtn` from

```
HorizontalOptions="Center"
```

To

```
HorizontalOptions="Fill"
```

or

```
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
```

Comment: I didn't understand your answer.. are you saying it is a known bug in MAUI .. Also I don't want the button to fill the screen .. I want it to expand as the text increases.. Moreover i expect similar behavior on all platforms.. because it is working as expected on windows..

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can check the updated part.